# ignore empty values (or null) while passing JSON request to third party

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

I am passing request in JSON format to third party system but they want only to pass field which is not null else skip that field. I am trying to build logic to skip Null/Blank. Can someone please help.

Example :

```
{
    "group": "AA",
    "effectiveDt": "2019-12-31T12:00:00",
    "accountName": "ABCDDDDD",
    "Number": ,
    "trackingId": "122111xxx222"
  }
```

As  "Number" is null so request should only have below field

```
{
    "group": "AA",
    "effectiveDt": "2019-12-31T12:00:00",
    "accountName": "ABCDDDDD",
    "trackingId": "122111xxx222"
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you're using and show where you're stuck in your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to generate JSON in Apex code is to use the [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) and that now includes this method:

```
public static String serialize(Object objectToSerialize, Boolean suppressApexObjectNulls)
```

that will not serialize `null` values when `suppressApexObjectNulls` is set to `true`.

**PS**

If the source of the data is an SObject (or some other sort of map where you know the keys) you can iterate over the fields and replace empty strings with nulls before serializing:

```
YourType__c sob = ...;
for (SObjectFied f : YourType__c.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
    if (f.getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
        if (sob.get(f) == '') sob.put(f, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working actually. For example this code ```Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>{
        'x' => 'x',
        'y' => '',
        'z' => null
};

system.debug(JSON.serialize(m, true));``` gives me this output: ``{"z":null,"y":"","x":"x"}``. Moreover, it will not suppress empty strings anyway, and the question is stated about this option too.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova See the PS.

Comment: Yes, sure, I understand, how to remove empty strings, however, ```suppressApexObjectNulls``` does not remove nulls, as it described in documentation.
In my example it is shown with 'z' key, that appears in debug.

Comment: Thanks Keith !! This solution worked perfectly !!

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova My bad. I get the same result as you. Seems like `suppressApexObjectNulls` of `true` is broken.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Posted https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265649/has-json-serialize-suppressapexobjectnulls-ever-worked on that.